Llama2 7b pretrained model to sagemaker registry
I am trying to download pretrained model to se and deploy it to sagemaker endpoint.( don't want to use jumpstart)
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download
snapshot_download(repo_id="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")

I am able to download but not able to understand how to convert it to tar.gz which I can upload it to s3 and then create endpoint on sagemaker.
